# How can I find \$A \beta \$ step by step?

Tags: loop-gain

The following is a question from 8.18 in  *[Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf)*, page 342.

Consider the circuit in this following figure. \$(\frac{W} {L})_{1-4} =\frac{50} {0.5} \$, \$|{I_D}_{1-4}| = 0.5\ \mathrm{mA}\$, \$R_2 = 3\ \mathrm{k\Omega}\$.

[image]

Calculate the closed-loop gain and output impedance.

The answer I found from internet ([solution link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5l5JHTunnJiZWM1YWRjMTctMDYxNi00ZDZkLTk2OTAtZTE1MzJiZTU2Nzlm/view?resourcekey=0-OQwkkoFwDWJhUndfr72e8A)).
[image]

$$A \beta = \frac{V_F} {V_t} = \frac{1} {R_2} (R_1 \parallel R_2) \frac{r_{o3}} {(R_1 \parallel R_2) + \frac{1} {g_{m1}}} g_{m2} (r_{o4} \parallel (R_1 + R_2) \parallel r_{o2}) \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$$

My question is, how can I derive this equation? Any details?

[image]

The answer from internet seemed to suggest that

$$\frac{V_x} {V_t} = \frac{1} {R_2} (R_1 \parallel R_2) \frac{r_{o3}} {(R_1 \parallel R_2) + \frac{1} {g_{m1}}}$$

Where does that come from?

Here is my equation.

[image]

$$\frac{V_p} {R_1} - \frac{V_t - V_p} {R_2} = -V_p g_{m1} + \frac{V_x - V_p} {r_{o1}} \tag{1}$$

$$-\frac{V_x} {r_{o3}} = -V_p g_{m1} + \frac{V_x - V_p} {r_{o1}} \tag{2}$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{V_x} {V_t} = \frac{R_1 r_{o3} (1 + g_{m1} r_{o1})} {R_1 r_{o1} + R_1 r_{o3} + R_2 (R_1 + r_{o3} + r_{o1} + R_1 g_{m1} r_{o1}) }$$

Voltage -Voltage feedback

Comment: you wrote "The answer I found from internet". What does this mean? No reference? How can you be sure that "the answer" is correct? It seems that you have opened the loop at the node Vout, correct? Then, why the loop gainis not defined as Vout/Vt ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5l5JHTunnJiZWM1YWRjMTctMDYxNi00ZDZkLTk2OTAtZTE1MzJiZTU2Nzlm/view?resourcekey=0-OQwkkoFwDWJhUndfr72e8A

Comment: @LvW I don't know if the answer from internet is correct. Do you have the correct answer?

Comment: Isn't the step to find the open-loop gain and feedback factor already presented in the Razavi book?

Comment: @internet Which page? I think the one from the book is different from here.

Comment: @kile - below the last diagram you gave an expression for Vx/Vt. The 1st part of this expression must give the voltage division between Vt and Vp. Here you have considered the two external resistors (R1 and R2) only. This cannot be true because there is a current going into the node Vp. Hence, Vp depends also from the input resistance r_in at this node (source).  Here we have r_in=1/gm1

Comment: If I ignore ro1 I can find the voltage gain Vx/Vt by inspection. The CG stage gain is \$\frac{V_X}{V_P} = g_m*r_{o3} = \frac{r_{o3}}{\frac{1}{g_m}}\$ and the input resistance effect \$\frac{V_P}{V_T} = \frac{R_1||\frac{1}{g_m}}{R_2 + (R_1||\frac{1}{g_m})}\$ Thus, the voltage gain is \$\frac{V_X}{V_T} =\frac{R_1||\frac{1}{g_m}}{R_2 + (R_1||\frac{1}{g_m})}  \frac{r_{o3}}{\frac{1}{g_m}}\$

Comment: @G36 - I think that you did not consider the negative feedback effect on the final gain (caused by resistors in the source path), Such an effect does also exist in common gate configurations (which applies here for the expression Vx/Vt.)

Comment: @LvW "This cannot be true because there is a current going into the node Vp" Can you draw a diagram to illustrate what you mean? Where is the current you are referring tot?

Comment: @G36 What's your equation if you don't ignore \$r_{o1}\$?

Comment: But the main point and advantage of this method (finding the loop gain) you have should learn from the book is to quickly find the approximate solution without involving much of a math. So you should have not expect to find solutions that gives exact numerical solutions in this chapter. They are just approximation solutions.

Comment: @kile - you are asking "Where is the current you are referring to ?".
I suppose you are aware of the fact that there is a current going into the source node - do you need a diagram to verify this? Or did I misunderstand your request?

Comment: @LvW The current going into source node of M1 is

$$-V_p g_{m1} + \frac{V_x - V_p} {V_x} $$

Comment: @LvW Please take a look at my new diagram and updated question.

Comment: Your expression for Vx/Vt gain including ro1 is correct.

Comment: @G36 How do I know when I should I omit \$r_{o1}\$? Why do you  choose to ignore \$r_{o1}\$ instead of \$r_{o3}\$?

Comment: @G36  Whoes \$\frac{V_x} {V_t} \$ is corect? Lvw or mine?

Comment: I do not see LvW equation. Your full equation for Vx/Vt gain is correct.

Comment: @One more thing, do you think the way to break the loop here is correct?

Comment: @G36 - first  question: The expression Vx/Vt gives the gain of a common-base stage when the input signal Vt is applied through a resistor (resp. a voltage divider. Do you agree? Second question: Will such a source resistor provide negative feedback (as in a common-emitter stage) ? What are your answers? Yes or no? If yes, your expression for Vx/Vt is wrong.

Comment: @G36 - sorry, I have to apologize.  I have confused DC feedback with signal feedback. This CB-stage has negative DC feedback but no signal feedback. Tha means: Your expression for Vx/Vt (including gm) is correct.